# recall method instead of recall activity android

Tags: android

These are two audio and video queues. I want them to repeat 7 times.

But the for loop and while loop doesn't work. It seems that all the reputation will be executed in parallel.

Also I can recall the `Activity`.

But I want a way to call audio and video itself several times (for example 7 times) one after each other.

Any assistance is appreciated.

This is part of my code:

```
Public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            SharedPreferences appSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                boolean doAudio= appSettings.getBoolean("audioCue", true);
                boolean doVideo= appSettings.getBoolean("videoCue", true);
                String audioFreqS = appSettings.getString("audioFrequency", "400");
                float audioFrequency = (float)Integer.parseInt(audioFreqS);
            String audioLoudnessS = appSettings.getString("audioLoudness", "100");
                float audioLoudness = ((float)Integer.parseInt(audioLoudnessS))/100.0f;

        // determine whether estimation or cue mode is active
        if (!currentlyEstimating) {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

                // determine random timespan for cue(s)
                initCueLength();

                // use video cue, i.e. display colored block for the specified time

                    if (doVideo) {
                            switch         (Integer.parseInt(appSettings.getString("cueBackgroundColor", "1"))) {
                        case 1: 
                            videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                                 videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            break;
                    case 3:       
                        videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);       
                            break;
                        case 4:    
                             videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            break;
                        case 5:    
                               videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            break;
                        default:      
                        videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);       
                            }
                        // after the delay specified for postDelayed, set background to black
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                videoLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);      
                            }
                        }, cueLength);
                        loopnum++;
                        }


                    if (doAudio) {
                                // TODO integrate sound playing
                            final SoundGenerator task=new SoundGenerator();       
                        task.keepPlaying(true);
                        task.setLoudness(audioLoudness);
                        // start sound generator with the specified frequency (Hz)
                        task.execute(audioFrequency);
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                                public void run()
                            {
                                    task.keepPlaying(false);
                                }
                        }, cueLength);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing audio and video is done asychonously, so if you just make a loop you'll end up with the sound played 7 times in parallel. You might trigger repeat at the end of playing e.g. the sound, passing a decreasing counter along and stop repeating when the counter reaches 0.

Comment: You mean that for example like this? counter =0;   while(counter<7) { .....      counter++;}    I tried this way. But it didn't work.